# R tibble group_by slice. Can't repeat SAS result

Tags: r, sas

I have got SAS script working correctly:

```
data dt;
  input usubjid trt $ dt;
datalines;
1 P 1
1 P 2
1 P 3
1 P 4
1 O 5
1 O 6
1 O 7
1 P 8
1 P 9
1 P 10
2 P 21
2 P 22
2 P 23
2 P 24
2 O 25
2 O 26
2 O 27
2 P 28
2 P 29
2 P 30
;

proc sort data=dt;by usubjid dt trt;run;

data dt2;
  set dt;
  by usubjid trt notsorted;
if first.trt or last.trt then output;
run;
```

This script selects first and last row for **trt** group. Please note, that **trt** group can be repeated after other **trt** in the same patients.

The result is:
[image]

Can't figure out how to do the same in R using *tibble* **group_by** and **slice**.

R data for repeating SAS output proposed:

```
library(tidyverse)
tribble(
    ~usubjid, ~trt, ~dt,
    1,         "P",   1,
    1,         "P",   2,
    1,         "P",   3,
    1,         "P",   4,
    1,         "O",   5,
    1,         "O",   6,
    1,         "O",   7,
    1,         "P",   8,
    1,         "P",   9,
    1,         "P",  10,
    2,         "P",  21,
    2,         "P",  22,
    2,         "P",  23,
    2,         "P",  24,
    2,         "O",  25,
    2,         "O",  26,
    2,         "O",  27,
    2,         "P",  28,
    2,         "P",  29,
    2,         "P",  30
 ) -> dt
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create new groups based on `consecutive` values, and then `filter`. By default, `group_by` groups by identical values (even if they are not consecutive). If you don't have dplyr 1.1.0, you can use `data.table::rleid` instead of `consecutive_id`:

```r
library(dplyr) #1.1.0 and above
dt %>% 
  group_by(usubjid, cons_trt = consecutive_id(trt)) %>% 
  filter(row_number() %in% c(1, n()))

   usubjid trt      dt cons_trt
     <dbl> <chr> <dbl>    <int>
 1       1 P         1        1
 2       1 P         4        1
 3       1 O         5        2
 4       1 O         7        2
 5       1 P         8        3
 6       1 P        10        3
 7       2 P        21        3
 8       2 P        24        3
 9       2 O        25        4
10       2 O        27        4
11       2 P        28        5
12       2 P        30        5
```